# dispatch_after error: '[AnyObject]?' is not a subtype of 'Void'

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I am trying to do a very simple delay of popping to the root view controller with this code:

```
let delay = 1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))
dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
  self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
})
```

Yet I am getting the error `'[AnyObject]?' is not a subtype of 'Void'` I assume that it has something to do with calling `self.navigationController` inside the block/closure because if i comment out that line and replace with `println("Will this compile")` it works.

Can someone please explain why I am getting this error and what the correct way to achieve what I am trying to do is?

Xcode 6.1.1

Thank you.

Comment: self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true) returns [AnyOject] as return value. But the dispatch_after( ) has the block return type as Void, That's the problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In swift single statement closures automatically return the statement return value. In your specific case, it's attempting to return an instance of `[AnyObject]?`, which is the return value of `popToRootViewControllerAnimated`. The closure expected by `dispatch_after`is `Void -> Void` instead. Since the closure return type doesn't match, the compiler complains about that.

To fix the problem, simply add an explicit return statement:

```
dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
    return
    ^^^
})
```

Comment: Ahhh okay, that makes perfect sense. When I looked at the error and the type returned by `popToRootViewControllerAnimated` I saw that but thought I am not returning anything so I didn't understand why I was getting that error. Everyday is a school day, thanks Antonio